# .class exception when calling a method

Tags: java

I am trying to create a small program that allows me to update an objects value. However i keep getting a .class expected error.

1. I have the method labelled static to allow me to call within my main method
   this is a method in my main class i am trying to call a method in my student class to update the credits.

   ```
   public static void doUpdate(MyStudent myStudent) {
     System.out.println("Enter credits: ");
     int numCredits = in.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Enter letter grade: ");
     String letterGrade = in.next();
     myStudent.takeClass(int numCredits, String letterGrade);
   }
   ```
2. this is my method from my student class type

   ```
   public static void takeClass(int numCredits, String letterGrade) {
     // didn't think code was needed as it is pretty rudimentary
   }
   ```

What is causing this to ask for a .class expected at my int numcredits paramter in the calling of takeClass

Comment: Please provide the complete message. And add the complete classes you refer to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a method, you don't pass the type of the parameters, only the values.

Replace :

```
myStudent.takeClass(int numCredits, String letterGrade);
```

With

```
myStudent.takeClass(numCredits, letterGrade);
```

Comment: @PrincessLulu please accept the answer if it solved your query.

Comment: will do as soon as the time limit ends